# append link in fullcalendar eventRender dont call a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a question about Fullcalendar, append in EventRender and javascript.

I have this

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
                if (event.noLaboral == true) {
                    element.find('.fc-event-title').append("</br>");
                }
                else{
                    element.find('.fc-event-title').append(" hour &nbsp;<a href =/User/Index/100022/Event/View/"+ event.id +"   class='search'><i class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i>&nbsp;search</a> ");
                }
```

my javascript is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.search').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
            alert(id);
        });
    });
</script>
```

if I put this

```
<a href =/User/Index/100022/Event/View/"+ event.id +"   class='search'><i class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i>&nbsp;search</a>
```

outside calendar, the function `$(.'search').click` work, the javascript stop the redirect event and print the url in the screen, but if put this tag with append in eventRender, inside in the calendar like show you, dont work!!!why???.

Answer (score 0):

Your click will never work because when you define

```
$('.search').click(function (e) {...})
```

the calendar is not loading, so there is no `<a>...</a>`

Try to put your code in `eventAfterAllRender` (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/)

I think it should works

Hope it could help you.